# I want to make a infinite scroll on a static table using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, static, infinite

I have a html table that looks like this:

```
<table class="data-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Faculty</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Capacity</th>
        <th>Semester</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td><a class="course" href="#">ACT201</a></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><a class="faculty" href="#">Ani</a></td>
        <td>MW 11:20 AM - 12:50 PM</td>
        <td>NAC993</td>
        <td>41(42)</td>
        <td><a class="semester" href="#">Spring 2020</a></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

There will be many more rows on  section. What I want to do is hide all the rows except first 50. When user scrolls to the bottom of the table another 50 rows will show and so on.

**So, basically what I want to do is make a infinite scroll on a static table (without loading data from another page using ajax).**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [jquery.tableScroll](https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.tableScroll), but I highly recommend using a newer "vanilla JS" library such as [Clusterize](https://clusterize.js.org/) to accomplish scrolling tables.